# ElasticSearch Query_String ignore field if not available in the document

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

The document in elastic has field mappings only for the fields **catalog** and **@type**. now if a user sends an non-existing field (**countryCode**) in the search, is there a way in elastic to instruct to ignore the field in the search ?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {                       
                        "query": "(\\*catalog\\*:Trunk) AND (\\*@type\\*:Product) AND (\\*countryCode\\*:USA)"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By default it does a strict match and return 0 results since countryCode is not a valid field

Comment: You need to parse the query and do it yourself. This is one of the reasons it's rarely a good idea to let your end users provide the search string to `query_string` directly.